# Travis deploy to Github for multiple platforms

Tags: linux, macos, build, travis-ci

I need to setup deployment in Travis CI into Github Releases for Linux and Mac.
How one can have binaries related to OS ?

Travis have `$TRAVIS_OS_NAME` env. variable, but it only gives you `linux|osx`. Is there a way to have platform specific (x86, x64) binaries?

[My travis config](https://gist.github.com/r8d8/64edf20b9e12a283ece2a0a58d8a9cb9)